# $h$ is non-identity element whose square is identity $\implies\langle h\rangle$ is normal

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

> $h$ is non-identity element whose square is identity $\implies\langle h\rangle$ is normal

If the whole group is $G$ and $h\in G$ with the property above then $\langle h\rangle=\{1,h\}$. Clearly $1$ commutes with all elements, hence to check is: $ghg^{-1}=h$

> **EDIT**
>
> OK, You say that the statement is false, but can you translate what the first sentence on page $44$ means (it begins with ''Since the condition...'')[image]

Comment: To problem now is that the statement is obviously false. For example in the cyclic group $\mathbf S_3$ the element $(1,2)$ that swaps 1 and 2 satisfies the condition, but $\langle (1,2)\rangle$ is not a normal subgroup.

Comment: The claim is false, for example $\;(12)\in A_4\;$ . The claim is true though if you require $\;h\;$ to be the **only** such element.

Comment: @Timbuc True, except that $(12)\not\in A_4$.

Comment: @Timbuc where does it fail, is the condition, $ghg^{-1}=h$ not sufficient ?

Comment: $\left(ghg^{-1}\right)^2=h^2=1$ --> where does this come from?

Comment: @inequal It'd be if you could prove $\;ghg^{-1}=h\;$ **for all** $\;g\in G\;$ , but you can't *unless* you require uniqueness. You also write $\;G= G^2\;$ which is greatly false as well in the general case.

Comment: If it were to hold, yes. However, to remain in $S_3$, one has $(13)(12)(13) = (23)\not\in\langle (12)\rangle$. (for instance) @Myself: I think he means $(ghg^{-1})^2=gh^2g^{-1}=gg^{-1}=1$.

Comment: $ghg^{-1} = g^{-1}hg$ is strange. Remember that $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, you proved that $ghg^{-1} = ghg^{-1}$. Great job!

Comment: @Timbuc I think you found the point $G^2\neq G$.

Comment: @inequal That is only *one* point. There are others: $\;ghg^{-1}=h\;$ is unbased, and simply false,  in the general case, say.

Comment: That first sentence on p. 44 says that if $x$ is not the identity and $x^2$ is the identity, then $gxg^{-1}$ has the same two properties for every $g \in G$. Therefore if there is a unique element $x$ of $G$ with those properties, we have $gxg^{-1} = x$ for all $g$, so the subgroup $\langle x\rangle$ is normal.

Comment: @KCd where is the uniqueness required ? I don't see it.

Comment: Um, if there is a unique element satisfying certain properties then two elements that satisfy those properties must be the same. Thus $gxg^{-1} = x$ for all $g$. How else would you be concluding that $gxg^{-1} = x$ if you do not bring in the uniqueness??

Answer (score 1):

In general the statement is false. What is true is the following. Let $g \in G$, $g \neq 1$, and $g^2=1$. Then $\langle g \rangle$ is normal if and only if $g \in Z(G)$, the center of $G$.